# Time module: Couldn't find a version that satisfies the requirement

Tags: pip, pycharm, python-module

I've tried to run this code:

```
from time import clock

def f2():
    t1 = clock()
    res = ' ' * 10**6
    print('f2:', clock()-t1)
```

but got Traceback:

```
from time import clock
ImportError: cannot import name 'clock' from 'time' (unknown location)
```

Python doesn't see the time module in the standard library?

I tried to install this module manually via pip (Yes, I know that it should already be installed. But what else could I do?). I got the following error in response:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement time
ERROR: No matching distribution found for time
```

Trying to install the module via PyCharm also failed - it just runs pip and gets the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Method `clock()` in module `time` was deprecated in 3.8, see [issue 36895](https://bugs.python.org/issue36895).

So i used `time.time()`

```
import time

def f2():
    t1 = time.time()
    res = ' ' * 10**8
    t2 = time.time()
    print('f2:', t2 - t1)
```

Strange, but while googling the problem, I noticed that many people in 2019-2021 (after `clock(`) deprecated in Python 3.8) had this error, but no one wrote how to solve it.
So my answer might be really helpful.